How to use loadCount?
I have Factory which hasMany Category which hasMany Product in my model. So for example the Category looks like this:
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }

    // ...
}

I am trying to list the categories and I want to add the count of products to each category on this list.
What I am doing currently is
    $factories = Factory::all();
    $factories->load('translation');
    $factories->load('categories');
    $factories->load('categories.translation');
    $factories->load('categories.products');

Now the problematic part that I don't want to load the complete product list, just the count of the products. I found that there is this loadCount method, which should do exactly what I need, though I am not sure how to use it.
When I do $factories->loadCount('categories.products'), then I got an error message: "Call to undefined method App\Models\Factory::categories.products". Not to mention that I am not sure how to get just the count without lazy loading the whole thing just by accessing products. Can somebody explain how this is supposed to work?

First you should use eager loading even if in this case it doesnt change performance much but with it we can use withCount() method
$factories = Factory::query() //using query() first is IDE friendly
    ->with([
        'transalation',
        'categories' => function($category) {
            $category->withCount('products')->with('translation');
        },
    ])->get();

This will return the same result as your code example without the loaded products and add on each category the attribute product_count with the count of its products.
If you have a scope or something to filter the products over, you do it like this
$factories = Factory::query() //using query() first is IDE friendly
    ->with([
        'transalation',
        'categories' => function($category) {
            $category
                ->with('translation')
                ->withCount(['products' => function($product) {
                    $product->where('active',true); //or ->active() if its a scope
                }]);
        },
    ])->get();

Using load eager loading
$factories = Factory::all();
    $factories->load('translation');
    $factories->load(['categories' => function($category) {
        $category
            ->with('translation')
            ->withCount(['products' => function($product) {
                $product->where('active',true); //or ->active() if its a scope
            }]);
    }]);


I am explicitly asking for eager loading with the load method, because it gives a better quality code imho. Isn't there a way to solve this with loadCount?

@inf3rno there is but it would look the same as query eager loading. will add it the the answer. Using load instead doesnt provide better quality code in my opinion. Factory::with('translation')->with('category.transaltion')->get() look nice too.

Okay. Meanwhile I found that my solution does not work because loadCount does not support dot notation.

It does not seem to work properly, I have as many DB Queries as many categories I have. I use it this way: $factories->load(['categories' => function ($category){$category->withCount('products');}]); and {{$category->products()->count()}}.

I'll open a different question to address this. Technically what you posted is good, but somehow eager loading does not seem to work. This might be even a Laravel bug, who knows.

@inf3rno I doubt that it's a laravel/eloquent bug, the package is pretty rigid as of now. Ping me when you post your question :D

I sent a bug report, we'll see.

This is my bug report: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/52782 I tried to fix this behavior with raw SQL, and categories.translation started to behave the same way which was previously fine. So I am pretty sure this is a bug. Though I am not a Laravel expert. Maybe there is another explanation.

@inf3rno Your issue is in the blade. you are using {{$category->products()->count()}} when there is an eager loaded attribute $category->product_count. The first one will trigger a request per $category (since you are explicitly using the query builder products()) and the second one is the eager loaded one.

@inf3rno as for your second issue, it is related to how you are loading the relations. you are loading categories then loading categories.translation which will trigger from loaded categories. use only $factories->load('categories.translation'); to load both categories and their translation. if you need to load two relations of categories or more, then use the format I used in the 3rd example in this answer.

@inf3rno it's $category->products_count with an 's', can't edit the comment anymore

I tried out with products_count, it works, but I still have multiple queries with it.

@inf3rno you need to debug and remove code to get the culprit. remove any $category->products() and the $factories->load('categories') lines

I used your third example, now it works. Not sure what went wrong yesterday. I'll close the error report.

Thanks for your help!
